# Acumatica PXGraphExtension - Table doesn't exist

Tags: acumatica

Apologies, I am new to Acumatica and can't find anything online about this customized BLC (business logic code) problem.

I have made an extension off the existing class, "Testing" and copied the PXSelectJoin statement from the original class which uses a InventoryTranHistEnqResult. Problem is however whenever I include InventoryTranHistEnqResult in any PXSelectJoin, it will have a runtime error saying: Table 'InventoryTranHistEnqResult' doesn't exist.

Looking at the SQL profiler, it seems InventoryTranHistEnqResult is made up of different tables and there is indeed no table called InventoryTranHistEnqResult. So how can I modify the PXSelectJoin using InventoryTranHistEnqResult?

DAC:

```
public partial class InventoryTranHistEnqResult : PX.Data.IBqlTable { #region GridLineNbr
    // just for sorting in gris
    public abstract class gridLineNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected Int32? _GridLineNbr;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Grid Line Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Visible = false)]
    public virtual Int32? GridLineNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._GridLineNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._GridLineNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region InventoryID
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected Int32? _InventoryID;
    [Inventory(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
    public virtual Int32? InventoryID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InventoryID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._InventoryID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region TranDate
    public abstract class tranDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected DateTime? _TranDate;
    [PXDBDate()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date")]
    public virtual DateTime? TranDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TranDate;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TranDate = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region TranType
    public abstract class tranType : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected String _TranType;
    [PXString(3)] // ???
    [INTranType.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tran. Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual String TranType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TranType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TranType = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region DocType
    public abstract class docType : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected String _DocType;
    [PXDBString(1, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Doc Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Visible = false)]
    public virtual String DocType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DocType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DocType = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region DocRefNbr
    public abstract class docRefNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected String _DocRefNbr;
    [PXString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reference Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INRegister.refNbr>))]
    public virtual String DocRefNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DocRefNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DocRefNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region SubItemID
    public abstract class subItemID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Int32? _SubItemID;
    [SubItem(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Subitem")]
    public virtual Int32? SubItemID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SubItemID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SubItemID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region SiteId
    public abstract class siteID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected Int32? _SiteID;
    //[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)] //???
    [Site(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Warehouse")]
    public virtual Int32? SiteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SiteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SiteID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region LocationID
    public abstract class locationID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected Int32? _LocationID;
    //            [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)] //???
    [Location(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Location")]
    public virtual Int32? LocationID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LocationID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LocationID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region LotSerialNbr
    public abstract class lotSerialNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected String _LotSerialNbr;
    [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lot/Serial Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual String LotSerialNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LotSerialNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LotSerialNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region FinPerNbr
    public abstract class finPerNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { };
    protected String _FinPerNbr;
    [GL.FinPeriodID()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Fin. Period", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual String FinPerNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._FinPerNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._FinPerNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region TranPerNbr
    public abstract class tranPerNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { };
    protected String _TranPerNbr;
    [GL.FinPeriodID()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tran. Period", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual String TranPerNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TranPerNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TranPerNbr = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Released
    public abstract class released : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected bool? _Released = false;
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Released", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual bool? Released
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Released;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Released = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    //  Qtys in stock UOM here #region BegQty
    public abstract class begQty : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _BegQty;
    [PXDBQuantity()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Beginning Qty.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? BegQty
    {
        get
        {
            return this._BegQty;
        }
        set
        {
            this._BegQty = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region QtyIn
    public abstract class qtyIn : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _QtyIn;
    [PXDBQuantity()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty. In", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? QtyIn
    {
        get
        {
            return this._QtyIn;
        }
        set
        {
            this._QtyIn = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region QtyOut
    public abstract class qtyOut : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _QtyOut;
    [PXDBQuantity()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty. Out", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? QtyOut
    {
        get
        {
            return this._QtyOut;
        }
        set
        {
            this._QtyOut = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region EndQty
    public abstract class endQty : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _EndQty;
    [PXDBQuantity()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ending Qty.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? EndQty
    {
        get
        {
            return this._EndQty;
        }
        set
        {
            this._EndQty = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region UnitCost
    public abstract class unitCost : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _UnitCost;
    [PXDBPriceCost()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unit Cost", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? UnitCost
    {
        get
        {
            return this._UnitCost;
        }
        set
        {
            this._UnitCost = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    // not used currently : #region ExtCost
    public abstract class extCost : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _ExtCost;
    [PXDBBaseCury()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Extended Cost", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? ExtCost
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ExtCost;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ExtCost = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region BegBalance
    public abstract class begBalance : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _BegBalance;
    [PXDBBaseCury()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Beginning Balance", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? BegBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._BegBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            this._BegBalance = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion #region EndBalance
    public abstract class endBalance : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Decimal? _EndBalance;
    [PXDBBaseCury()]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ending Balance", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual Decimal? EndBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return this._EndBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            this._EndBalance = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

BLC:

```
public class Testing_Extension:PXGraph<InventoryTranHistEnq> {

public PXFilter<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter> Filter;

[PXFilterable]
public PXSelectJoin<InventoryTranHistEnqResult,
    CrossJoin<INTran>,
    Where<True, Equal<True>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.gridLineNbr>>> ResultRecords;
public PXSelectJoin<InventoryTranHistEnqResult,
    CrossJoin<INTran>,
    Where<True, Equal<True>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.gridLineNbr>>> InternalResultRecords;
public PXCancel<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter> Cancel;
public PXAction<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter> viewSummary;
public PXAction<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter> viewAllocDet;

protected virtual void InventoryTranHistEnqFilter_StartDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        DateTime businessDate = (DateTime)this.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
        e.NewValue = new DateTime(businessDate.Year, businessDate.Month, 01);
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

public override void Initialize()
{
    ResultRecords.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
    ResultRecords.Cache.AllowDelete = false;
    ResultRecords.Cache.AllowUpdate = false;
}

protected virtual IEnumerable resultRecords()
{
    int startRow = 0;
    int totalRows = 0;
    PXResultset<InventoryTranHistEnqResult> usortedList = InternalResultRecords.Select();
    if (usortedList.Count == 0)
        return usortedList;
    decimal beginQty = ((InventoryTranHistEnqResult)usortedList[0]).BegQty ?? 0m;
    List<object> list = InternalResultRecords.View.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, new object[PXView.SortColumns.Length], PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow, 0, ref totalRows);
    foreach (PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult> item in list)
    {
        InventoryTranHistEnqResult it = (InventoryTranHistEnqResult)item;
        it.BegQty = beginQty;
        decimal? QtyIn = it.QtyIn;
        decimal? QtyOut = it.QtyOut;
        beginQty += (QtyIn ?? 0m) - (QtyOut ?? 0m);
        it.EndQty = beginQty;
    }
    return list;
}
protected virtual IEnumerable internalResultRecords()
{
    InventoryTranHistEnqFilter filter = Filter.Current;

    bool summaryByDay = filter.SummaryByDay ?? false;
    bool includeUnreleased = filter.IncludeUnreleased ?? false;

    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.inventoryID>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, false);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.finPerNbr>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, false);  //???
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.tranPerNbr>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, false);  //???


    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.tranType>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.docRefNbr>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.subItemID>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.siteID>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.locationID>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.lotSerialNbr>(ResultRecords.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible(Tran.Cache, null, !summaryByDay);

    var resultList = new List<PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult, INTran>>();

    if (filter.InventoryID == null)
    {
        return resultList;  //empty
    }

    // it's better for perfomance to calc. BegQty in the separate GROUP BY query before main.. but currently as is

    PXSelectBase<INTranSplit> cmd = new PXSelectReadonly3<INTranSplit,

            InnerJoin<INTran,
                            On<INTran.tranType, Equal<INTranSplit.tranType>,
                                    And<INTran.refNbr, Equal<INTranSplit.refNbr>,
                                    And<INTran.lineNbr, Equal<INTranSplit.lineNbr>>>>,

            InnerJoin<INSubItem,
                            On<INSubItem.subItemID, Equal<INTranSplit.subItemID>>,
            InnerJoin<INSite, On<INSite.siteID, Equal<INTran.siteID>>>>>,

            OrderBy<Asc<INTranSplit.tranDate, Asc<INTranSplit.createdDateTime, Asc<INTranSplit.lastModifiedDateTime>>>>>(this);

    cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.inventoryID>>, And<Match<INSite, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>();

    if (!SubCDUtils.IsSubCDEmpty(filter.SubItemCD))
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INSubItem.subItemCD, Like<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.subItemCDWildcard>>>>();
    }

    if (filter.SiteID != null)
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.siteID, Equal<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.siteID>>>>();
    }

    if ((filter.LocationID ?? -1) != -1) // there are cases when filter.LocationID = -1
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.locationID, Equal<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.locationID>>>>();
    }

    if ((filter.LotSerialNbr ?? "") != "")
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr, Like<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.lotSerialNbrWildcard>>>>();
    }

    if (!includeUnreleased)
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.released, Equal<boolTrue>>>();
    }

    // commented because we need all the trans to calc BegQty        
    //            if (filter.StartDate != null)
    //            {
    //                cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.tranDate, GreaterEqual<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.startDate>>>>();
    //            }

    if (filter.EndDate != null)
    {
        cmd.WhereAnd<Where<INTranSplit.tranDate, LessEqual<Current<InventoryTranHistEnqFilter.endDate>>>>();
    }

    PXResultset<INTranSplit> intermediateResult = (PXResultset<INTranSplit>)cmd.Select();

    decimal cumulativeQty = 0m;
    int gridLineNbr = 0;

    foreach (PXResult<INTranSplit, INTran, INSubItem> it in intermediateResult)
    {
        INTranSplit ts_rec = (INTranSplit)it;
        INTran t_rec = (INTran)it;

        if (ts_rec.TranDate < filter.StartDate)
        {
            cumulativeQty += (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty) ?? 0m;
        }
        else
        {
            if (summaryByDay)
            {
                if ((resultList.Count > 0) && (((InventoryTranHistEnqResult)resultList[resultList.Count - 1]).TranDate == ts_rec.TranDate))
                {
                    InventoryTranHistEnqResult lastItem = resultList[resultList.Count - 1];
                    if (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty >= 0)
                    {
                        lastItem.QtyIn += ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastItem.QtyOut -= ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                    }
                    lastItem.EndQty += ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                }
                else
                {
                    InventoryTranHistEnqResult item = new InventoryTranHistEnqResult();
                    item.BegQty = cumulativeQty;
                    item.TranDate = ts_rec.TranDate;
                    if (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty >= 0)
                    {
                        item.QtyIn = ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                        item.QtyOut = 0m;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.QtyIn = 0m;
                        item.QtyOut = -ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                    }
                    item.EndQty = item.BegQty + (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty);
                    item.GridLineNbr = ++gridLineNbr;
                    resultList.Add(new PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult, INTran>(item, null));
                }
                cumulativeQty += (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty) ?? 0m;
            }
            else
            {
                InventoryTranHistEnqResult item = new InventoryTranHistEnqResult();
                item.BegQty = cumulativeQty;
                item.TranDate = ts_rec.TranDate;
                if (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty >= 0)
                {
                    item.QtyIn = ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                    item.QtyOut = 0m;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.QtyIn = 0m;
                    item.QtyOut = -ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty;
                }
                item.EndQty = item.BegQty + (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty);

                item.InventoryID = ts_rec.InventoryID;
                item.TranType = ts_rec.TranType;
                item.DocType = ts_rec.DocType;
                item.DocRefNbr = ts_rec.RefNbr;
                item.SubItemID = ts_rec.SubItemID;
                item.SiteID = ts_rec.SiteID;
                item.LocationID = ts_rec.LocationID;
                item.LotSerialNbr = ts_rec.LotSerialNbr;
                item.FinPerNbr = t_rec.FinPeriodID;
                item.TranPerNbr = t_rec.TranPeriodID;
                item.Released = t_rec.Released;
                item.GridLineNbr = ++gridLineNbr;
                item.UnitCost = (t_rec.BaseQty != null && t_rec.BaseQty != 0m && t_rec.TranCost != null && t_rec.TranCost != 0m) ? t_rec.TranCost / t_rec.BaseQty : t_rec.UnitCost;
                resultList.Add(new PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult, INTran>(item, t_rec));
                cumulativeQty += (ts_rec.InvtMult * ts_rec.BaseQty) ?? 0m;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}


public override bool IsDirty
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void Redirect(string finPeriodID, int? inventoryID, string subItemCD, string lotSerNum, int? siteID, int? locationID)
{
    InventoryTranHistEnq graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryTranHistEnq>();

    graph.Filter.Current.InventoryID = inventoryID;
    graph.Filter.Current.SubItemCD = subItemCD;
    graph.Filter.Current.SiteID = siteID;
    graph.Filter.Current.LocationID = locationID;
    graph.Filter.Current.LotSerialNbr = lotSerNum;

    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, Messages.InventoryTranHist);
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see definition of DAC for TableOne and TableTwo?

Comment: I have added the start of both tables. They both have many more PX.Data.IBqlField. I am thinking now, could it be that TableOne is actually just a temporary table? I do not have direct access to the database to check.

Comment: Have you tried attaching SQL profiler to see query that is being executed? That could help you troubleshoot problem.

Comment: Is the namespaces all same? Also i would suggest to clear your temp files and rebuild the project again as sometimes it may cause some problems which we will never solve.

Comment: So after looking at the SQL profiler, it seems TableOne is actually not a table but a DAC using a number of tables. However, when I try to use it in a PXSelect of my Testing_Extension BLC, it treats it as a table? I have updated to include the original Testing BLC.

Comment: I'm confused, the code sample above is incomplete... not possible to help with this.

Comment: Have you gone through all the developer training and certifications by the way?

Comment: I have updated the full DAC and BLC. What I don't get is why when I copy the exact same PXSelectJoin, it gives me the table not found error. The DAC doesn't look any different to me. How does it know to use other tables?